# render a part of the Account page based on the user being part of the Account team

Tags: apex, rerender

I'd like to render a part of the Account page based on the user being part of the Account team. I am getting stuck at generating the Boolean to Render.

Here's my attempt:

```
public class AccountTeamChecker {

 Account a;

    public AccountTeamChecker(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

   a = (Account) controller.getRecord();        

  }

        UserInfo.getUserId();


  public List<AccountTeamMember> AccountTeamFolk() {
      return [select Id, UserId from AccountTeamMember where accountid = :a.id ];
    }

 public boolean RenderRevenue;{

     if (UserInfo IN: AccountTeamFolk){
         RenderRevenue= True;
             } else{
                 RenderRevenue=False;
                 }

 }

  }
```

Does the IN: not work here, like I use in triggers?
Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'IN' at line 20 column 18

Comment: SOQL works the same in controller and other classes as it does in triggers. But you appear to be trying to use it outside of SOQL and have a variety of other syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to meet your requirement that leaves most of the work to the SOQL query by just returning the number of matches via [count()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm). It also uses a lazy initialization approach in the `get` that often works well in controller classes to make sure that a property is always initialised (and once only) before it is accessed.

```
public class AccountTeamChecker {
    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public AccountTeamChecker(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }
    // Returns true if the user is an account team member
    public Boolean renderRevenue {
        get {
            if (renderRevenue == null) {
                renderRevenue = [
                        select count()
                        from AccountTeamMember
                        where AccountId = :sc.getId()
                        and UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
                        and AccountAccessLevel in ('Read', 'Edit', 'All')
                        ] > 0;
            }
            return renderRevenue;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. I have in my VF page the following: <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="accountContactExt, AccountTeamChecker" rendered="renderRevenue"> so if the value renderRevenue is true, the VF page should render, correct? Not quite working yet. Also why does system.debug('==================='+renderRevenue); in the line after return RenderRevenue generate error - Error: Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 19 column 13 
thanks

Comment: On the last point, code placed directly after a return (that means jump out of here back to the calling code) can never run so you are being warned. Put the debug immediately before the return. On the first point to access the controller property you need to use `rendered="{!renderRevenue}"`. But I'd expect you to be doing that on a part of the page not the root element of the page itself: do you really want a blank screen when `renderRevenue` is false?

Comment: Thanks. Debug firing ok now. As for rendered issue, it's ok to un-render a whole page for now, just testing. Except I can't get it render even after adding myself to the team...

Comment: I am not getting an queries at all on the DEBUG logs. Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20

Comment: I don't understand why my debug log doesn't show my system.debug command.

Comment: @jaw999 Two common reasons: 1) each log file has got so big (more than 2M) that your logging has fallen off the end; 2) you have to (if using the web setup UI) keep re-setting the user as a monitored user every 20 requests.

Comment: hmm. Well it is working now when I made the change in VF page - rendered="{!renderELEMENT}"> and comment out the line about AccountAccessLevel in the Class. But I don't see why I'd need to comment that out. My access is ALL

Comment: But when I login as another user who is on the accountTeam, it renders with the lines included

Comment: @jaw999 This site isn't intended to create long comment threads. If you hit something that you can't figure out or work-around, post another question with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a set of the UserIds of the account team members instead then you can check if that set contains the current users id.
Here is an example of a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626664/check-if-an-apex-list-contains-an-object